# Perl: how to increment a Class::Struct field?

Tags: perl, class

How do I increment a field in a [`Class::Struct`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Class/Struct.html) object?

For now I am stuck with

```
use Class::Struct foo => [
  counter => '$',
];
my $bar = foo->new(counter => 5);
$bar->counter($bar->counter()+1);
```

I wonder if there is something more expressive than the last line (the obvious `$bar->counter++` results in `Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call`).

EDIT: of course, I am not interested in `$bar->[0]++` et al - what if I add a field before `counter`? I don't want to have to hunt my code for all such "bugs-in-waiting".

Comment: In general, I'd advice you away from Class::Struct, it's a severely outdated module. In Moose for example you could easily solve this using a Counter native trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, try doing this :

```
use strict; use warnings;

use Class::Struct foo => [
  counter => '$',
];
my $bar = foo->new(counter => 5);
print ++$bar->[0];
```

or using a SCALAR ref (no need to hard-code the "path" like the previous snippet) :

```
use strict; use warnings;

$\ = "\n";

use Class::Struct foo => [
  counter => '*$',
];
my $bar = foo->new(counter => 5);
print ++${ $bar->counter };
```

Comment: this is no good: I don't want to access the field by its address; if I wanted to do that, I would have been using arrays

Comment: @SinanÜnür: how is it worse than `bar.counter++` in `C`?

Comment: Just because all your friends are jumping off the bridge, do you have to do that as well? Ask yourself: "How do I begin to debug if `$bar->counter` is returning unexpected values?" When all increments happen through `increment_counter`, you can add trace statements to that. When your code messes with the internals of `$bar` willy-nilly, you are lost in spaghetti. In C, you should have `increment_foo_counter(struct foo *bar)`. Of course, I am assuming there is a point to using `Class::Struct` rather than a plain hash `%bar`.

Answer (score 6):

You can add an `increment` method to `foo`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package foo;

use strict; use warnings;

sub increment_counter {
    my $self = shift;
    my $val = $self->counter + 1;
    $self->counter($val);
    return $val;
}

package main;

use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Class::Struct foo => [
  counter => '$',
];

my $bar = foo->new(counter => 5);

$bar->increment_counter;

say $bar->counter;

__END__
```